# Python factory, where object parameters can be specified gradually?

Tags: python-3.x, factory-pattern

Assuming we have the following object (in reality many more parameters):

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, h, w, color):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.color = color
        print(f'Room is {self.h}*{self.w} and painted in {self.color}')


Room(0, 1, 'red')  # Room is 0*1 and painted in red
```

Further assume we need to create this object hundreds of times. A few of the parameters need to be changed each time. However, most of the parameters stay consistent within one "session". Therefore, I would like to fix those parameters at the beginning of my session, to make the subsequent calls much simpler.

My current approach looks like this. Surely there is something better out there?

```
class RoomFactory:
    def __init__(self, h=None, w=None, color=None):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.color = color
        # TODO: Get arguments from Room.__init__ automatically?

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs_already_set = {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v}
        return Room(**kwargs_already_set, **kwargs)


# Define some parameters at session beginning. Which parameters depends on session! 
rf = RoomFactory()
rf.h = 5
rf.w = 5

# Later, create hundreds of objects with different remaining arguments
rf.create(color='green')  # Room is 5*5 and painted in green
rf.create(color='black')  # Room is 5*5 and painted in black
```

Comment: Take a look at `functools.partial()`.

Comment: @gebbissimo If or when you get this working, please share the code. I want to see how you implemented this. Thanks.